# Disable flycheck-mode and prettify-symbols-mode

Tags: emacs

My emacs.d clones from [purcell/emacs.d: An Emacs configuration bundle with batteries included](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d)

It enable  `prettify-symbols-mode` and `flycheck-mode` as default.

Search the custom.el but did not find related  setting .

How could disable them from my `init.el`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(prettify-symbols-mode -1)`

`C-h f prettify-symbols-mode`:

> ```
> prettify-symbols-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ‘prog-mode.el’.
>
> (prettify-symbols-mode &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle Prettify Symbols mode.
> With a prefix argument ARG, enable Prettify Symbols mode if ARG is
> positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
> the mode if ARG is omitted or nil.
>
> When Prettify Symbols mode and font-locking are enabled, symbols are
> prettified (displayed as composed characters) according to the rules
> in ‘prettify-symbols-alist’ (which see), which are locally defined
> by major modes supporting prettifying.  To add further customizations
> for a given major mode, you can modify ‘prettify-symbols-alist’ thus:
>
>   (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
>             (lambda ()
>               (push '("<=" . ?≤) prettify-symbols-alist)))
>
> You can enable this mode locally in desired buffers, or use
> ‘global-prettify-symbols-mode’ to enable it for all modes that
> support it.
> ```

This applies to almost every minor mode.